# What's the best way to provide Google Analytics access in these circumstances without exposing all Google Analytics data?

Tags: google-analytics

In essence, an Important Affiliate links to a URL at a domain registered by Client. This URL redirects to a specific landing page for this Affiliate on Client's main domain. The landing page has URL /offer and has a CTA to Client's purchase funnel.

As the first URL redirects to the second URL, there is no referrer for GA.

Affiliate would like to see Google Analytics data relating to the traffic that Affiliate sends to Client - sessions, transactions, Goals (including entrances to purchase funnel). Client does not want to expose all Client's GA data to Affiliate.

What's the best way to provide such access?

I initially thought of Filters on a specific View for the Affiliate. But of the options that are available, I don't think any of them will help.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options to get analytics data to Affiliate without giving them access to the GA account at all, and based on your list of the data they are interested in, it sounds like such a solution could work. The options vary in level of detail as well as setup time and need for technical resources, so hopefully something suits.

1. Custom dashboard with PDF emailed to Affiliate regularly (GA can do the emailing automatically). This is good if they are interested in totals and percentages, less so if they want session-by-session detail.
2. [Google Data Studio](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6283323) report with view-only access given to Affiliate. I believe that even in a view-only interaction you can allow controls such as setting the date range, and the tables (which you can filter as needed) will allow paging through all rows.
3. Custom spreadsheet compiled using the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4). You can do this with a [Google Sheets GA add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on), which can be set to update itself on some regular schedule. You can also construct a CSV file with Python or another supported programming language, which is good if you need to get around sampling to make sure all transactions are included (for example).

You could also set up a custom report or small family of custom reports to email as PDFs, but I don't think that has anything to recommend it over any of the 3 options above.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know why I didn't think of that in the first place. I'm inclined in that direction because it seems more optimal than the other potential possibilities we've thought of.

Comment: unfortunately, Affiliate is insisting on GA access.

Comment: Could you add UTM parameters to the /offer redirect so it has identifiable source/medium? I believe you would be able to filter based on that, though I'd need to check.

Comment: thanks for responding. GA Filter can Include Medium, Source or Campaign but doesn't seem to work for me. I can see my test traffic in my normal View but not in the Filtered view. Next I thought I might record the UTM in a Custom Dimension and Filter on that - but if the Medium etc Filters don't work...

Comment: So the traffic is showing with the correct UTM data in your normal view but the filters aren't getting it? Let me pull up the filter screen and see whether I can pick out anything to check.

Comment: thanks for your help so far. I didn't think to check whether GA was working properly or at all on this particular page - I have now, and it isn't. So I'm off to fix that, and try again. sigh :)

Comment: It's those things "beneath" what you're actually working on that always get you! Let me know how it goes. :-)